# Phantom git commit hash

Tags: git

```
git show <commit hash>
```

Using the above command with a specific commit hash shows the contents of a commit. However using any of the following returns no results:

```
git branch --contains <commit hash>
git log --grep=<commit hash>
git reflog show --all | grep <commit hash>
<Searching for commit in gitlab>
```

Can you explain what could have caused my repository to get into the state and what this state is. Also, if it is obvious, how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I would think that it's an "unreachable" commit. Maybe you amended a commit or reset to an earlier commit?

Answer (score 3):

What you're describing is pretty standard behavior.  If you were to "change" a git by:

- amending it
- rebasing
- squashing it into another one
- etc.

Then the original commit still *exists*, but is no longer referenced by any branches in your repository, making it "unreachable".   Note that I put "change" in quotes because the root of this behavior is that you *can't* change a commit; you can only replace it with a new one.

This unreachable commit may eventually disappear due to normal garbage collection behavior.  It would also not show up in any clones of your repository.

Comment: I'd edit this to say "…no longer referenced by anything in the repository: branches, tags and other commits".

Comment: I thought about that, but in fact the abandoned commit *could* still be referenced  by a tag, but would still not show up in e.g., `git branch --contains` or in `git log`, etc.  I was trying to avoid diving too deep :).

Comment: The confusing bit is it does appear in clones.

Comment: @George: Is there by chance a tag referring to it? Any possibility of sharing the actual repository with us?

Comment: It's not a public repo, so sorry I can't share. I will check for tags

Comment: Does `git describe --all` yield anything?

Comment: It turns out it was attached to a branch (a cherry pick one). When I explicitly checked it out ```git branch --contains``` lists it